# Building node.js from sublime text (ERROR: The process "node.exe" not found.)

Tags: node.js, sublimetext2

Step 1 : I installed node.js and used package control to install nodejs package for sublime.

Step 2 : Modified the sublime-settings to below

```
{
// save before running commands
"save_first": true,
// if present, use this command instead of plain "node"
// e.g. "/usr/bin/node" or "C:\bin\node.exe"
"node_command": "\"C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe\"",
// Same for NPM command
"npm_command": "\"C:/Program Files/nodejs/npm\"",
// as 'NODE_PATH' environment variable for node runtime
"node_path": "\"C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe\"",

"expert_mode": false,

"ouput_to_new_tab": false
}
```

Step 3 : I created a simple js file with console.log("Hello World");

When tried to build using Tools -> Build, It does print Hello World in the console, but also gives me the error

```
ERROR: The process "node.exe" not found.
```

Any help would be really appreciated as to why I'm getting this.

Thanks.

EDIT : I was able to fix it by removing the following from nodejs.sublime-build

```
"windows": { "cmd": ["taskkill /F /IM node.exe & node", "$file"] }, "linux": { "cmd": ["killall node; node", "$file"] }
```

Comment: might be a stupid question, but I assume you've verified that if you go to your command line and type C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.ex that it works as expected?  As a further stupid question, are you sure you don't need to use backslashes in there, since it's Windows?

Comment: Thanks @Paul. There's no question that's stupid when you're trying to help :) I was able to fix it by removing the following from nodejs.sublime-build   ,
  "windows":
    {
     "cmd": ["taskkill /F /IM node.exe & node", "$file"]
    },
  "linux":
    {
        "cmd": ["killall node; node", "$file"]
    }

Comment: Yeah, sorry I can't help more, I run node on *nix and Mac, haven't rolled it on Win yet.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, instead of removing this line from  nodejs.sublime-build

```
"windows": { "cmd": ["taskkill /F /IM node.exe & node", "$file"] }...
```

you can replace with

```
"windows": { "cmd": ["taskkill /F /IM node.exe & node 2>null", "$file"] }...
```

this allows to redirect the annoying error message of the TASKILL command to null.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, apply absolute path of node.exe installation folder in nodejs.sublime-build file as follows:

```
"windows": {"cmd": ["C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe", "$file"]} ...
```